# resourcemodel 'failed opening' error

Tags: error, model, resource-model

I attempt to call a resourceModel, however, I only recieve a white screen and the following error message within my log:

> Warning: include(Namespace/ProjectName/Model/Mysql4/Projectname.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This is how i'm calling the above:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('projectname/projectname')->uploadData();
```

This is how the resourceModel is defined in the config.xml:

```
<models>
    <projectname>
        <class>Namespace_ProjectName_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>projectname_mysql4</resourceModel>
     </projectname>
....
</model>
```

And finally, this is the resourceModel itself:

```
class Cjponyparts_ProjectName_Model_Mysql4_ProjectName extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
    ....
    function uploadData(){....}
}
```

The resourceModel is located at:

Namespace/ProjectName/Model/Mysql4/ProjectName.php

The only difference I see that could cause this error is that I have the resourceModel defined as like this "ProjectName.php" while it looks for something like this "Projectname.php".  Is this the problem?  How can I fix?  Do resourceModels need to be defined as the second option?

Comment: Try `Mage::getResourceModel('kitinventory/projectname')`

Comment: @R.S derp, that was the projectname initially before I removed it :D  it should (and does) read 'projectname/projectname'.

Comment: Try change ProjectName.php to Projectname.php and update the class accordingly \

Comment: or Mage::getResourceModel('kitinventory/projectName')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take a look at the error message

> Warning: include(Namespace/ProjectName/Model/Mysql4/Projectname.php): failed to open stream

```
Failed to open Projectname.php
```

Try change the class and file name to not be camel-case

Namespace/ProjectName/Model/Mysql4/Projectname.php

```
class Cjponyparts_ProjectName_Model_Mysql4_Projectname extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
    ....
    function uploadData(){....}
}

Mage::getResourceModel('kitinventory/projectname')
```

If you want to keep the name camel case try

```
Mage::getResourceModel('kitinventory/projectName')
```